# How to validate access to Apex API with an Integration User

Tags: rest-api, integration, connected-apps

I use an Apex REST API for communication with Java, which authenticates in the Connected App using the login and password data of any user along with the provided User Details. I was informed that, for communication with a Salesforce API, it is a best practice to use an Integration User for authentication and communication. However, I cannot access the **Manage Connected Apps** tab because the integration user does not have access to my data. Therefore, I am unable to generate the necessary data to log in to the API through Java in the way I am accustomed to.

Is there any other way to **generate the authorization token** for requests to the REST API when your user is an integration user?

Comment: Assuming that by _Integration user_ you mean a user account with [Integration User license](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.integration_user.htm&language=en_US&type=5), then what you're seeing is expected. Typical flow: a SF admin or user with enough privileges sets up the integration user and connected app, then hands the credentials to the "client" party.  If you're both the admin and the owner of the client, then you need enough permissions to complete the first step.